# Meaning and use of `reltol` in `nnet` library in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm trying to use the `nnet` library in R, and can't seem to work out how to use the `reltol` parameter. It says in the docs:

> Stop if the optimizer is unable to reduce the fit criterion by a factor of at least 1 - reltol.

I assume this means that if `reltol = 0.5` then it will stop if it can't halve the error rate, and if `reltol = 0.1` it will stop if it can't reduce the error rate by 10%. Is that correct? The experiments that I've done don't seem to work like that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is what it is supposed to mean.

A `reltol` parameter is common in optimisation functions in R and other mathematical and statistical systems.

In `nnet`, it has the default `reltol = 1.0e-8`.  In the more often used `optim` in the `stats` library the statement is:

> `reltol`
>
> Relative convergence tolerance.
>   The algorithm stops if it is unable to
>   reduce the value by a factor of `reltol * (abs(val) + reltol)` 
>   at a step. Defaults to `sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)`,
>   typically about `1e-8`.

You can see why it has `sqrt` since it might be looking at an amount of about `reltol^2`